# ActiveRecord with Postgres: Has Many Through and Indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

Let's say you have three models:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, through => :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

With indexes like so:

```
add_index :users, :collection_id
add_index :comments, :user_id
```

If you have the collection query for its comments:

```
@collection.comments
```

Will it use both of the indexes?

**Edit:**

This produces a query that looks like:

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "users" ON "comments"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."collection_id" = 232
```

Using EXPLAIN it claims it's only using "Index Scan using index_users_on_collection_id on users"

So presumably it gets the users quickly from the User's index on collection_id, but then searches through ALL the comments when joining on them with users?  Will this query not perform well if there are lots of comments (hypothetically, like 100,000)?

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than a vague description of what the `EXPLAIN` output is, why not show it?  Even better, show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, so we can see the *expected* rowcounts and costs and the *actual* rowcounts and timings.  Also, don't expect the plan on a large dataset to be the same as it is on a small one.

Comment: Execution plans are not made hypothetically, they're made with estimates of the current cardinality and selectivity of the filter and join fields under consideration.  If you think the plan would be slow with 100K comments, it only matters if you produce the plan with 100K comments and current statistics.  If you have an actual performance problem, run and post `explain analyze` as @kgrittn suggests.

Comment: Typically a comment is from *one* user. So your data model may not suit the requirements. Should probably be n:1 instead of n:m - a table `comment` with a foreign key column referencing the author (`user`).

Comment: It's really easy to insert 100,000 records (or orders of magnitude more) using rails in development, staging, whatever and run the explain again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the EXPLAIN plan for a small table to be the same for a large table.  Plans change as table sizes change.

This being said if it does end up doing a sequential scan through comments and there are a large number of rows, then you may want to make sure there is an index on the foreign key field on the comments table.  PostgreSQL will use the index if it assesses that this will be a net win from a disk I/O perspective and that means that the table is large enough to benefit from using an index scan, and that the index scan will not retrieve a large portion of the table.